# .htaccess RewriteCond REQUEST_URI not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm currently having a lot of struggle setting up this very simple .htaccess on my website.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/page
RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /page
RewriteRule (.*) pageroot/$1
```

I think the code is self-explanatory. 
I don't know why but when there is /page in my url, it still get redirected to webroot.
Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to your 2nd rule changing REQUEST_URI to `/pageroot/`.

**root .htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(page|pageroot/|webroot/)
RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
```

**/pageroot/.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /pageroot/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Your answer is right but it still doesn't work because indeed I have anoter .htaccess file in my page folder.

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?/$1 [L]

Comment: I'm now getting an
'The requested URL /page was not found on this server.'
error.

The page .htaccess is in the pageroot folder, I have no page folder.
When I said page folder I meant pageroot folder

Comment: Well sorry for the imprecision, I was reffering to the folder containing my page files, which is actually named pageroot

Comment: ok check updated code for `/pageroot/.htaccess`